# Access Query: Replacing Null With Zero

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table with Division, Service_Category, and Years_Of_Service.  The Service_Category field has 7 unique values; "0 Mon to 6 Mon", "6 Mon - 1 Year", "1 - 2 Years", "2 - 5 Years", "5 - 10 Years", "10 or More Years", and "Not Listed".

For a given set of query parameters, the Service_Category field may not have a value for all 7 Service_Category types.  In a simple example, if my query results contained 7 records, where all but the "Not Listed" Service_Category had a count of 1 in the "Years_Of_Service field.  I would like for the 7th record to return a "0" in the "Years_Of_Service field for the record having "Not Listed" in the Service_Category field.

I've been playing around with the "NZ" function, but I can't get the query to do what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use `IIF` - have you looked into that?

Comment: Or you could always post some sample data and desired outcome, which you'd probably get an answer fairly quickly

Comment: ... and the query you tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the NZ to convert the null into a string, trim off any blanks (just to be safe) and then test for the length of the string. If the string is greater than zero, you have a value, otherwise you are "Not Listed"

```
iif (Len(Trim( nz(Service_Category,"")))>0,Service_Category,"Not Listed")
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I was attempting to provide some sample data for perspective.  What is the best way to do that.  Does this site support providing an upload file?

Comment: Just edit your question and add the sample data like its code.